# Object.create() and toString()

Tags: javascript, inheritance, object, prototypal-inheritance

Given these code

```
var Person = function(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
};

Person.prototype = {
  toString: function() { return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName; }
};

var test4 = Object.create(Person);
test4.firstName = "Phat4";
test4.lastName = "Wang4";
console.log(test4.toString === Object.toString); // true
console.log(test4.toString === Function.toString); // true

var test5 = { firstName: "Phat5", lastName: "Wang5" };
console.log(test5.toString === test4.toString); // false
console.log(test4.toString === Function.toString); // true
console.log(test5.toString === Object.prototype.toString); // true

console.log(test5.toString()); // [object Object]
console.log(test4.toString()); // Function.prototype.toString called on incompatible object
```

Why does the last line `console.log(test4.toString())` throws error ? It shows that `test4.toString` is not like `test5.toString` but I don't get it ..

Ps. I've tried searching the threads and still cannot answer myself. Sorry if this duplicates with any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
var test4 = Object.create(Person);
```

You should be doing:

```
var test4 = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

The way you had it, `test4` had the `Person` *function* in its prototype chain, not the intended prototype object that has your `toString` method.

Because of this, it was using a `toString()` method that is apparently anticipating being called against a `Function` object.

Comment: So that mean `test4.toString()` is `Function.toString()` which overrides `toString()` method inherited from Object, right ?

Comment: @PhatWangrungarun: Yes, it overrides the `Object.prototype.toString` method, which is the generic one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between assigning to a prototype and assigning a new property to the prototype of an object.

You declared a function Person as a constructor function, but then you are pretty much assigning something to its prototype by doing this:

```
Person.prototype = {
  toString: function() { return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName; }
};
```

That means you assigning a new object key value pair toString-function to Person.prototype, instead of actually adding a new property to it, in which you should have done like this:

```
Person.prototype.toString = function() { return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName; }
```

What entails from this is that when you are actually creating a new object that inherits from Person object by calling `Object.create`, then what happens in its implementation is a new object will be freshly created, and then it will return that new object which will override the prototype property that javascript assumed you have created by doing that `Person.prototype` assignment previously earlier in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Person = function(firstName, lastName) { 
    this.firstName = firstName; 
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }; var p1=new Person("Phat1","Wang1");
```

p1 is an Object

```
var p2= Object.create(Person);
p2.firstName="Phat2";
p2.lastName="Wang2";
```

p2 is a function